# При запуске выдает "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')

Tags: javascript

```
function figure(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,20,20);
    this.x = 20;
    this.y = 20;
    this.update = function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 470, 270);
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
    }
}

function right(){
    myFigure.x += 1;
    myFigure.update();
}

var myFigure;
function game(){
    myFigure = new figure();
}
```

Comment: Если и выдаёт ошибку, то, скорее, не в этом коде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишите вместо

```
var myFigure;
```

так

```
var myFigure = {};
```

глядишь, поможет

---

Хотя чисто гипотетически код рабочий даже без этой мелочи